# Why this operation returns False? (string.__class__ == "<class 'str'>")

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, class, boolean

I was wondering why I can't determine if an object is a string using **class**

```
string = "s"
print(string.__class__) # print(<class 'str'>)
print(string.__class__ == "<class 'str'>") # False
```

BTW I know that there is isinstance() function

Comment: `print(...__class__)` is not the same as `...__class__`. `print` invokes an object's `__str__` or `__repr__` methods.

Comment: Because you're comparing a class object to a string? This isn't javascript, where `typeof` returns a string.

Comment: `type(string)` avoids the dunder attribute use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `__name__` attribute:

```
>>>string.__class__.__name__ == 'str'
True
```

However, to use `__class__`, compare with `str` as a builtin:

```
>>>string.__class__ == str
True
```

Comment: is __class __ an instance variable?

Comment: @IslamMurtazaev Yes. `__class__` is an attribute of an instance of some other class. For instance, given `class Test: pass`, `Test.__class__` will return `<class 'type'>` (in Python3), since classes are an instance of the overarching `type` class. However, `t = Test();t.__class__` will return `<class '__main__.Test'>`, since `t` is an instance of `Test`.

Answer (score 3):

Those should be working for any string s:

```
s.__class__.__name__ == 'str'

type(s) is str
```

btw: i would suggest using the second one since it's more readable.